# How can we call JS function from the html content in bootbox dialog box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Code is to dynamically generate new rows in bootbox dialog box, which is called from JQuery Function. But to add new rows, the JS function `$("#add_row").click(function()` is not working when put in this way.
Can anyone help?

Code #1  (JQuery : Which displays the bootbox Dialog box)
Section `#quick_parameter_table` is displayed.

```
  $( "body" ).on( "click", ".js-quick-parameter-entry", function(event) {

         var msg = $('#quick_parameter_table').html();

           bootbox.dialog({  
              title: "Add the parameter values?",
                message: msg,
                buttons: {
                   success: {
                       label: "Submit",
                       className: "btn-success",
                       callback: function () {      


                       }}}
                       });
                       });
```

This section `'quick_parameter_table'` is called from a JQuery function. 
This contains ode to dynamically insert new rows to the table, which is called using #add_row in the 'Add Row' button.

Code #2

```
<section id="quick_parameter_table" style="display: none;">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                <tbody>
                    <tr id='addr0'>
                        <td>
                        1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='name0'  placeholder='Name' class="form-control"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='mail0' placeholder='Mail' class="form-control"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='mobile0' placeholder='Mobile' class="form-control"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id='addr1'></tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>

    <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
</div>
    </section>
```

JS Function to add new rows .

Code #3

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
      var i=1;
     $("#add_row").click(function(){
      $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input name='name"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td><input  name='mail"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Mail'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='mobile"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Mobile'  class='form-control input-md'></td>");

      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
      i++; 
  });
     $("#delete_row").click(function(){
         if(i>1){
         $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
         i--;
         }
     });

});
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/afgdk8jc/3/)

Comment: can u provide jsfiddle or other editor link with your source code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/afgdk8jc/

Comment: link the external files its giving js error

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/afgdk8jc/6/

can u check

Comment: Hi, have you made any changes ? the insert of rows works in html and js, but not when bootbox dialog is called..

Comment: you need to replace your bootbox plugin js file with above, i searched the file but that was not compatible for you original one. :(